# Delivery statistics for mobile push messages with AWS SNS and publish subscribe

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile, push-notification, amazon-sns

How to find out how many mobile push notifications are delivered to mobile devices via Amazon SNS?

I have set up mobile push notification using [AWS SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html) using the publish-subscribe model. Mobile applications subscribe to SNS topics and messages are published to topics and then get delivered to mobile devices.

[CloudWatch Metrics](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) doesn't seem to have this information. It has only things like number of messages published to topic.